# What is the point of @{'/path/to/static_content'} in PlayFramework?

Tags: java, playframework

If I'm writing an HTML template that contains a reference to a URL in Play!, then I can do it in one of two ways. Like normal HTML:

```
<img src="/public/images/bananas.png">
```

Or with the special `@{''}` wrapper:

```
<img src="@{'/public/images/bananas.png'}">
```

As far as I can tell, these two methods produce the exact same result, and I don't see a reason to make it any more flexible than it is.

So what's the purpose of the extra characters?

**EDIT**: Sorry, dumb question.

Comment: Never used your framework, but a shot in the dark says it's to accomodate virtual directories. Your site will rarely be in `/`, it will most likely be in `/app/`, so your first link would point to the wrong place on your production servers (but the right one on your development machine).

Comment: @Blindy I use the Play Framework and your comment is correct.  You may want to add that as an answer instead of a comment.  You should get credit for that.

Comment: Meh, it wasn't an answer, it was a guess, it's ok :) Personally I use ASP.NET and we have the concept of `~/path/` for these things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@{...}` wrapper adds the context path of your application to the path. Say you deploy your application to run under `http://example.com/application/` instead of directly in `http://example.com/` this means

```
<img src="@{'/public/images/bananas.png'}">
```

would become

```
<img src="/application/public/images/bananas.png">
```